# Update table after getting item(s) of it, using (for, loop)

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview, combobox, windows-forms-designer

How can i update TotalItems table, When I got some Items from TotalItems?

```
TotalItems: ID(int), ItemName(Nvarchar), StoreNumbers(int)      
Requests: RequestID(int), Requester(Nvarchar), ItemNumbers(int)
```

I used this, but do not work :

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string t;
    t = (gridItem.RowCount).ToString();

    db.DoCommand("insert into Requests(RequestID,Requester,ItemNumbers) values('" 
    + txtRequestID.Text + "','" + txtRequester.Text + "','" + txtItemNumbers.Text + "')");
    MessageBox.Show("Was Saved", "..", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

    for (int i = 0; i < gridItem.RowCount - 1; i++)
    {
        a = gridItem[2, i].Value.ToString();
        b = int.Parse(gridItem[3, i].Value.ToString());

        dt = db.MySelect("select StoreNumbers from TotalItems where ItemName='" + a + "'");
        comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "StoreNumbers";

        int count;
        int c;
        int.TryParse(comboBox1.Text, out c);
        count = c - b;

        db.DoCommand("update TotalItems set StoreNumbers='" + count.ToString() + "' where ItemName='" + a + "'");
    }
}

void show()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataBase db = new DataBase();
    dt = db.MySelect("select * from Items where RequestID='" + txtRequestID.Text + "'");
    gridItem.DataSource = dt;
    gridItem.Columns[0].HeaderText = "ID";
    gridItem.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Request Code";
    gridItem.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Item Name";
    gridItem.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Number(s)";

    dt = db.MySelect("select StoreNumbers from TotalItems where ItemName='" + txtItemName.Text + "'");

    txtStoreNumbers.DataBindings.Clear();
    txtStoreNumbers.DataBindings.Add("text", dt, "StoreNumbers");
}
```

As i said, my problem persists.
Example: I have 20 in 'StoreNumbers' column, when I get 2 Items from TotalItems, result must be 18 StoreNumbers in TotalItems so that it returns -2!, what's problem?

Comment: Any exception or error message?

Comment: Define "do not work". Does it throw an exception? Does it work and go through the loop, but when you look in the DB the values haven't changed? Does your computer start belching black smoke? or...? Also: it is a **really, really** bad idea to concatenate values into SQL. I'm going to create a product called `foo'; drop  table TotalItems;--`. Please look into *parameters*

Comment: There is any error but Stroenumbers does not update into TotalItems

Comment: right; where are you looking for TotalItems? is this on a central server? or is this in a database **file** that is part of your project? This question is important, because there's a common mistake that people make when using database files in the project.

Comment: also: there's a race condition if you `select` the value then `update` based on it - in many ways, it would be preferable just to do an in-place update, i.e. `update TotalItems set StoreNumbers = StoreNumbers - @count where ItemName = @itemName` - this avoids half of the round trips, and avoids data corruption when more than one caller is doing this at once.

Comment: It's part of my project and connection string works good.

Comment: I want to know, is my snippet correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comments, asking about where the database is:

> It's part of my project

Then I *will bet* that the problem is that your looking at the table in database file in the project. The problem is, that isn't where the app executes: the app executes in `bin/debug` / `bin/release` (since this looks like a desktop application). When you build the project, the database file is **copied** into the execution location. When you run the application, it is therefore manipulating the **copy** of the database file. So: if you want to know if it has updated anything, you can't look at the database file in the project. You need to look at the **copy** of the database file *in the execution folder*.

Also:

- ADO.NET parameters; use some
- race condition on the fetch/update (you have no concurrency protection - with more than one caller, you **will** corrupt the data)

Comment: app executes in bin/debug.

Comment: When I add or delete Items from database table, it works good.